# How can I compute the accuracy of the classification tree from rpart when xval is not 0?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I want to compare the performance of the model with kNN and Naïve Bayes. But the problem is that I can't interpret the result in the form of accuracy. In this case, I did not set any training and test set but set xval = 10 in the process. So, how can I calculate the model's accuracy?

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. There's very little information here for folks to go on—we know nothing about your models or the parameter choices you're asking about. If the question is about calculations or interpretation more than code, it might be better suited on [stats.se], but even that much is unclear right now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.